# how to display image in megamenu(static content) magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, megamenu

I am trying to display image on megamenu dropdown,
so I am adding an image on static contents option which provides an option to insert image too,

`MGS -> Manage MegaMenu Items`
 and under various items, I added an image under static contents in the right content position

[image]

But on local testing, image has no content,

url for generated image is

```
http://webster-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/wysiwyg/Screenshot_2018-12-26_at_12.09.07_AM.png
```

Image doesn't display in the local

[image]

I am able to resolve why this url `http://webster-staging.s3.amazonaws.com/wysiwyg/Screenshot_2018-12-26_at_12.09.07_AM.png` generated by megamenu static content, doesn't work
Am i missing something?

Comment: There is no image in your url, try to add it manually `<img src="{{view url="images/imagename.jpg"}}" alt="image" />`

Comment: I added it manually.. via insert image option you can see the first image which I attached

Comment: please check this url: https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-2-x-manage-mega-menu.html